# Observable | async not maintaining data in component on return from combineLatest with 3 separate service calls

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

So I believe I understand what is happening...that everytime the selector is fired, it updates the entire state coming back from the ngRx store so FinData that had it's data loaded initially now becomes undefined when FranchiseData loads.  How do I prevent this from happening and simply return all of the data properly?  I am making 3 separate service calls and returning them in a combineLatest to determine if the routeGuard can activate.  All of them return data, but the issue is they don't maintain their data. One of them returns first in ngOnChanges and shows data but then the next one returns and the original one no longer has any data.  Any help is appreciated!

```
**parent.html**
<financial-data [finData]="financialData$ | async" [finFactors]="financialFactors$ | async" [franchiseData]="franchiseData$ | async"></financial-data>

**parent.component**

financialData$: Observable<financialData[]>;
financialFactors$: Observable<financialFactors[]>;
franchiseData$: Observable<franchiseData>
ngOnInit() {
  this.financialData$ = this.store.select(getFinancialData);
  this.financialFactors$ = this.store.select(getFinancialFactors);
  this.franchiseData$ = this.store.select(getFranchiseData);
}

**child.component**
@Input() finData: FinancialData[];
@Input() finFactors: FinancialFactors[];
@Input() franchiseData: FranchiseData;

ngOnChanges(changes) {
   if(this.finData && this.franchiseData && this.finFactors) { <--- this usually comes back with finFactors as undefined so it never runs this.getFinancials() but it never re-runs
      this.getFinancials();
   }
}

getFromStoreOrAPI(): Observable<any> {
  return combineLatest([
  this.store.select(getFinancialFactors),
  this.store.select(getFinancialData),
  this.store.select(getFranchiseData)
]).pipe(
  map(([financialFactors, financialData, franchiseData]) => ({
    financialFactors,
    financialData,
    franchiseData
  }))
);
}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | boolean {
    let tranId = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.tranId;
    let modelId = this.outer.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.modelId;

    this.store.dispatch(ScorecardActions.loadFinancialData({tranId: tranId}));
    this.store.dispatch(ScorecardActions.loadFranchiseData({tranId: tranId}));
    this.store.dispatch(ScorecardActions.loadFinancialFactors({modelId: modelId}));

    return this.getFromStoreOrAPI()
    .pipe(
        mapTo(true), <--- Neither one of these ever gets hit, I believe because it returning an array??
        catchError(() => of(false))
     );
   }
}
```

Comment: Observables provided to the router have to complete. The observable you return in `canActivate` doesn't complete.

Comment: How would I get it to complete?  In the ones I have individually I use .pipe(filter(x=> !!x), take(1))...could I do the same thing inside CombineLatest?  Or is there another method that would be preferred?

Comment: Yes you should use `take(1)` inside `getFromStoreOrAPI` or `canActivate`.